# Make intersection between plane and mesh more realistic

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, geometry, photorealism

I have a plane as the ground and a trapezoidal prism as a wooden leg (image below).

**How can I make the intersection between the ground and wooden leg more realistic?**

The ground is a flat, subdivided plane textured with a normal map and using Cycle's true displacement. The wooden leg is a slightly deformed cube with beveled edges.

[image: ground-wood intersection]

When zoomed out, the issue (leg looks like it is floating on top of ground) is more evident:

[image: ground-wood intersection zoomed out]

I am using Blender 2.82 with Cycles engine.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I looked at some reference pictures and i think the area around your plank could use some adjustments to make it more believeable.
For example:

- raise the ground a bit where the plank goes into the floor
- reduce the amount of moss directly around the plank (the moss in your render kinda looks like it's going into the plank)